# I am using "Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS" and not able to upgrade to 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04

["22.04.1 LTS is now available" showing on update manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqjqG.png)

When I click on upgrade button, update manager closes every time.

So I followed the steps below to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04.1 using the terminal.

`sudo apt update`:

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                         
Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                       
Ign:3 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 InRelease                                                                            
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                                                            
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                               
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/blaze/rtbth-dkms/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                      
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                            
Hit:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                            
Hit:9 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 Release                                                               
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                     
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-fonville/android-studio/ubuntu focal InRelease     
Get:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]              
Fetched 336 kB in 4s (83.7 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
prashant@prashantk01-notebook:~$
```

`sudo apt upgrade`:

```
prashant@prashantk01-notebook:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
#
# News about significant security updates, features and services will
# appear here to raise awareness and perhaps tease /r/Linux ;)
# Use 'pro config set apt_news=false' to hide this and future APT news.
#
The following packages have been kept back:
  android-studio
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
prashant@prashantk01-notebook:~$
```

`sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`:

```
prashant@prashantk01-notebook:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                       
Ign:2 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 InRelease                                                                            
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                         
Hit:4 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 Release                                                                              
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                               
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/blaze/rtbth-dkms/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                               
Hit:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                            
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                                
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                              
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-fonville/android- studio/ubuntu focal InRelease                          
Hit:12 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                      
Get:13 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports 
InRelease [108 kB]              
Fetched 336 kB in 4s (83.2 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
#
# News about significant security updates, features and services will
# appear here to raise awareness and perhaps tease /r/Linux ;)
# Use 'pro config set apt_news=false' to hide this and future APT news.
#
The following packages have been kept back:
 android-studio
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
prashant@prashantk01-notebook:~$
```

Above commands executed successfully.

`sudo do-release-upgrade -c`

Above command gives version update "New release '22.04.1 LTS' available".
[Checking for a new Ubuntu release
New release '22.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KqU2.png)

`sudo do-release-upgrade`

But I am not able to update with terminal or update-manager, gives below output
[Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riGaq.png)

Am I doing anything wrong here or do I need to wait?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1441848/edit) to show complete output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. Do not summarize -- those details are key.

Comment: I did the upgrade using update-manager.

Comment: All those 3rd party repositories are going to cause you problems. You need to at least resolve the android-studio problem to proceed. use ppa-purge to remove the android repo and downgrade the package(s).

Comment: Well android-studio isn't updated, maybe you locked/held it? `apt-mark showhold`, `sudo apt-mark unhold pkg`? You might want to `--allow-third-party` for you do-release-upgrade too.

Comment: thank you everyone, uninstalling android-studio worked